# How to get all string from json document in jsoniq or javascript?

Tags: xquery, jsoniq

I am trying to get all the values of json string as a single string. for example
in xquery xml

```
let $x := <a> welcome to the world of <b> JSONiq </b></a>
return string($x)
```

will return `welcome to the world of  JSONiq`

what is the equvalent result of of following documents in JSONiq:

```
let $y := {"a":"welcome to the world of ","b":" JSONiq"}
return xxxx($y)
```

The result should be same `welcome to the world of  JSONiq`
If you know in javascript also it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get all values, either with `libjn:values` or its definition, then you can use `fn:string-join` to get a single string:

So

```
declare namespace libjn = "http://jsoniq.org/function-library";
let $y := {"a":"welcome to the world of ","b":" JSONiq"}
return string-join(libjn:values($y) ! string(), "")
```

or

```
let $y := {"a":"welcome to the world of ","b":" JSONiq"}
return string-join($y() ! string($y(.)), "")
```

This might also return "JSONiqwelcome to the world of ", since the object keys are unordered

Comment: Hi Thanks,
first I could not test. in second it don;t work for complex json. would be nice if there the solution also in javascript. thanks

Comment: What do you want it to print for complex json?

Comment: You can see the query result from Benito here: http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/AE4TkOV6Xv5uO9oZBJKySg452ys%3D

Comment: @wcandillon Please try this(with complex json): 
http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/A4VLizHZgJQsd4s2vl0d6hjq%2Fpo%3D

Comment: @PrakashThapa: There you can call it recursively

Answer (score 1):

Find the recursive JSONiq script [here](http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/bf0zf8W%2B3sCE4P6T1bkor7ZE5qo%3D) for trying out.
Just doing typeswitch and recursive calls does it:

```
declare function local:strings($v as item()) as xs:string*
{
  typeswitch ($v)
    case $object as object() return
      for $k in jn:keys($object)
        return local:strings($object($k))
    case $array as array() return
      for $member in jn:members($array)
        return local:strings($member)
    default return $v
};

let $y := {"a":"welcome to the world of", "b":" JSONiq", "x":{"d":"m"}}

return string-join(local:strings($y), "@")
```

The "@" is only for showing where the borders are, can be replaced by "":

```
welcome to the world of@JSONiq@m
```

Hermann.